# How do I reference my model in a nested folder structure to dump data in Django 3.2?

Tags: django, seeding, dumpdata

I'm using Django 3.2 and Python 3.9.  I have this project directory setup

```
+ cbapp
    - manage.py
    - settings.py
    + models
        - __init__.py
        - crypto_currency.py
```

In my settings.py file, I have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cbapp',
]
```

I want to dump some data to a fixtures file, so I tried

```
$ python3 manage.py dumpdata cbapp.models.crypto_currency  > ./cbapp/fixtures/crypto_currency.json
CommandError: No installed app with label 'cbapp.models.crypto_currency'.
```

What's the proper way to reference my model to dump data?

Comment: `dumpdata cbapp.ModelName` with `ModelName` the name of the *model*.

Comment: That's a winner!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly in `cbapp/models/__init__.py` I think you have to import all models from `crypto_currency.py`. Like so: `from .crypto_currency import *`

Then you should be able to use (Replace `CryptoModel` with the name of your model):

```
python3 manage.py dumpdata cbapp.CryptoModel > ./cbapp/fixtures/crypto_currency.json
```

Comment: Thanks, gave this is a try but get the same error.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have your models folder inside the same folder as `manage.py`, try running `py manage.py startapp [appname]` and add it in settings.py in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then move your models folder to that new app